# Requirements for designing Location Based Service App

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, geolocation, nokia

I however, would like to design a mobile app using J2ME that can help users locate nearby resources in my city.

It is more like should use GPS to locate nearby resources like restaurants, saloons, car parks, hospitals to mention but a few.

I am requesting for what I need to pull this off. I have been reading through the threads, and it seems designing an LBS needs a huge amount of time.

What do i need to pull this off? I believe I can use Location API for J2ME. How can i integrate OVI maps ?

PS: do i need to use J2ME for this application ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just should download Google maps, play with it and find out that project your dreaming about has been already implemented. :(

Sorry for the bad news...

Comment: Not necessarily the case - apps like Yelp, etc, aren't necessarily tailored to OP's locale.

Answer (score 0):

The time required for your app is dependent of your expertise in developing the app.

For a quick look at j2me location based app (assuming you are using netbeans IDE) open New Project>Samples>Java ME Samples.. Select City Guide and have a look at it.

You can also use google Maps for this. Recently I was using google maps for my android app. Here is a code snippet:

```
public class GPS extends MapActivity 
{
    private LocationManager lm;
    private LocationListener locationListener;

    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mC;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        //---use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations---
        lm = (LocationManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);

        mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
        mC = mapView.getController();
    }
.. rest of the class..
```

For Java devices you need to use J2ME. Symbian probably uses C++ variations.